# How to install a .sql file using MySQL Command line Client

Tags: mysql, database, import, installation

I need to install or import a .sql file into an empty database that I've created. The .sql file will install all the tables etc.

When I click MySQL Command line Client prompt, I add my credentials and then...(to install / import the .sql file)?

Thanks guys!!

Comment: Ok, I've managed to install / import the .sql file. One thing I'd like to add to the answers below is when you type in the file name, eg: script.sql - make sure you include the path so that the command knows where to find the file, so you would put \. C:\yourdomains\thedomain\wwwroot\script.sql

Comment: Since you managed to solve your problem, please accept one of the answered that helped you - this will let people reading this page in the future know what helped. :)

Answer (score 29):

Something like this:

```
shell> mysql db_name < script.sql
```

...specify your options: --user, --password, --host, --port...

More information - [mysql — The MySQL Command-Line Tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html).

Answer (score 21):

From the MySql prompt, type:

```
\. file_name.sql
```

Comment: This is good to know, but it's slower than the mysql < file_name.sql when it contains 1000s of queries/inserts. For each insert, it will output:
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
, which can really slow things down.

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me was- on command prompt:

> mysql -u root -p < filename.sql

I read somewhere that to make things easier I should keep the file in the same root directory as my command prompt was in.
After running the above command, it asked me for the password. Typed the password, hit enter and I was back on my command prompt. Got pissed, opened mysql prompt, checked, the imported DB was present. Happy!

Comment: u might want to include database name also: "mysql -u root -DBASE <database_name> -p < filename.sql"

Comment: I found that you don't need the -DBASE parameter and may simply write "mysql -u root <dbname> -p < filename.sql"

Answer (score 2):

This is another way to do it in Linux

```
mysql databaseName -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD -e "source LOCATION_OF_FILE"
```

Example:

```
mysql studentDB -ustudent1 -pstuden1Pass -e "source /tmp/studentInserts.sql"
```

Answer (score 1):

just thought of perfecting the great answers from wise users.
before importing a .sql database

1. Create a new database or use existing database.
2. if your .sql file is saved in F as script.sql provide command as . F:\script.sql
   enjoy...